# Merging Columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have data from column 'D' to 'N' that I want to merge into one column without losing the data. I have tried this using the 'Merge Cells' option in the Home tab but then it discards all my data.

Is this possible to do in VBA?

Functions are of no use to me by the way.

Comment: You can use `CONCATENATE` formula as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

1. Insert column after N if not already blank
2. Enter formula `=CONCATENATE(D1,E1,F1,G1,H1,I1,J1,K1,L1,M1,N1)` in O1
3. Fill down
4. highlight column O and copy
5. right click column O and select select paste special then values
6. Delete columns D-N O is now your merged column and after delete is in Col D.

Assumption here are:

- there is no other data in D:O that you care about.
- having one column with all data is acceptable, you don't need the outer cells to remain independant.

Comment: Just a note that one can also do `=D1&E1&F1&...&N1)` instead of `=Concatenate()`...same results.

Comment: @pnuts - Just curious - when is `Concatenate()` better than just using `&`? (I'm not asking because I'm saying I'm right or anything, I'm just not too up to speed on the differences in `&` and `concatenate`.) What makes this circumstance better for `Concatenate`?  Edit: Okay perhaps "Appropriate" is the word I want, not "better" (see Excel Hero's comment :P )

Comment: @BruceWayne It is never better. The only purpose it serves is in a mythical future when ms finally makes it array-aware.

Comment: @pnuts - ah, that makes sense!  Thanks (and to Excel Hero too)!